# Custom Push Notifications

Tags: parse-platform

I am building a very basic information based app (Android) for an event, and i'd greatly appreciate your help on the questions below.

Basically, the app will just contain information about the 7 guest speakers at the event.

The attendees (2500 android users) will only get the link to the Android app when they arrive at the venue.

There is no database connected to the app as it just contains static information about the speakers which is hard coded into the app, however i want to build in a small feature so that i can send out custom push notifications to all users (let's assume 2500) at various times, such as when a speak is about to start on stage etc.

QUESTIONS

01 - am i right in saying that Parse allows you to send out custom push notifications in bulk from the Parse dashboard?

02 - is it able to send to 2500 at one time or do they need to be sent out in smaller batches?

03 - at what stage do charges start to occur for all of these custom push notifications

Thanks in advance for your help, it's much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**01.** Yes Parse dashboard enables you to send push notifications in bulk.

**02.** Yes it is able to send as many push notifications as needed you needn't worry about batches since Parse dashboard is a simple GUI frontend made by Parse.com so you don't do any coding.

**03.** You can see on this link https://parse.com/plans that per app you have 1 million unique pushes. Unique push is equal to 1 push on 1 device. To be clearer a single user might have 5 devices registered to him so sending a push to 1 user does not mean 1 push but 5 pushes 1 for each device.

**One more thing to note if you are going to be making custom pushes you should think about handling the push notification in the Android app if you plan on doing anything fancy. If its just to show the push with text then you need the basic handling of an incoming push that does nothing once the app is opened by a push notification.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering this, it is greatly appreciated.

The push notifications will just be an informative text, and no action will be included. Do i need to set something on the custom pushes to make sure they don't open the actual app, or try to perform a task?